# Getting amplitude of current pitch using core audio

Tags: ios, xcode, core-audio, fft, volume

I used [this tutorial](http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/) to create a small pitch detection app, however I'd like it to recognize the loudest instead of the highest pitch (within a certain frequency range).
I'd therefore need to get the amplitude of the current pitch to create a new bin-filter...
Any thoughts on how I could realize this?
As this is already using core audio (remoteIO) based samples, it seems unreasonable to use the regularly suggested AVAudioPlayer...

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you guys!!

Comment: Nothing? I didn't think this would be such a great issue. Do you gus need any further information?! I'd really need your help! Thanks!!